# how to add embed video inside E-mail?

Tags: php, email, video

Is it possible to add video inside E-Mail Content??

This is my mail Code

```
$to = 'my_mail@gmail.com';
$sub = 'my Subject';

$msg = '<html><body>';
$msg .= '<table rules="all" style="border: 1px solid #000000" cellpadding="10">';
$msg .= '<caption style="font-size: 18pt"><strong>Feedback from Customers</strong></caption>';
$msg .= "<tr><td width='25'><strong>Name</strong> </td><td width='60'>".strip_tags($_POST['name'])."</td></tr>";
$msg .= "<tr><td><strong>Email</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['mail']) . "</td></tr>";
$msg .= "<tr><td><strong>Country</strong> </td><td>" .strip_tags($_POST['country']) . "</td></tr>";
$msg .= "<tr><td><strong>Message</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']). "</td></tr>";
$msg .= "</table>";

//in here i want add viedo

$msg .= "</body></html>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
```

i want add `<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zsqtjnHQWQ8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>` inside email which send to customer.

How i can implement  that??

Comment: Can't you use an iframe to accomplish what you wan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of an `iframe` in an email message is not well supported. For more information see the [Link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/). Also it is not the correct way to embed a youtube video in email. If you go to YouTube and share a video via email with yourself you can inspect the html content of that email to discover how you should embed the video properly.

A static-clickable image that will redirect the user back to YouTube.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk_6r-b3kqU&feature=em-share_video_user">
 style="text-decoration:none;display:block" 
 class="nonplayable" 
 target="_blank">
  <img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Bk_6r-b3kqU/mqdefault.jpg" height="274" width="498">
 < /img></a>
```

A playable video(requires flash player)

```
<embed width="640" height="385" base="https://www.youtube.com/v/" wmode="opaque" id="swfContainer0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/Bk_6r-b3kqU?border=0&autoplay=1&client=ytapi-google-gmail&version=3&start=0">
```

It's because of security, it's the same reason you can't put JavaScript or anything external other than images in an email either - it can give the email too much 'power'. (You can put stuff there, it wont be displayed). Sadly this means no reliable flash support either.

**Gmail will parse the YouTube links and actually embed them for people who have it enabled.**

Answer (score 3):

From a User Experience perspective, there are a variety of reasons why embedding video on an Email is not a good idea. Consider the following:

1. You have no control over what kind of email client your recipients will use. Some people use clients that support only Plaintext. Other clients disable HTML by default.
2. Anti-spam systems will likely see this kind of content as a threat and block it.
3. It is not a good practice to make your user allocate inbox space to a video they may or may not want to see. Whenever possible, give your users the choice to consume or not your content.

Comment: 1) There is a practice called Graceful Degradation.. support what can be supported, provide fallback for features that aren't. For example, many HTML emails come with a link that says "Click here to view in browser", which would be useful in this case.. 2) List of emails that support iframes: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/ 3) embedding a video does not mean that the actual video is sent to the inbox.